# Is my LC3 solution correct for finding the length of an increasing sequence?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am asked to create a program in LC3 that recognises the maximum length of an increasing subsequence in a sequence of numbers.

Ex. {1,2,3,5,2,2,4,5,6,8,3,4}

**solution:** maximum increasing subsequence: {2,2,4,5,6,8} , maximum length of an increasing subsequence: 6

In order to do that , I am asked to create a subroutine called MAX_LEN that computes max(x,y) of two numbers x,y and has input x,y in R2,R5 and should give Output: max(x,y) in R5. Also I have to use another INC_SUB_LEN which computes the length of the first increasing subsequence from a given address. Input address is R0 and output length should be in R2. Maximum length so far in R5. I should also use the MAX_LEN subroutine. The large sequence from which we will find the subsequences is stored in adress DATA and its length in adress LENGTH. I am also given the commands at the end LENGTH .FILL x5000 and DATA .FILL x5001.

I am new in LC3 programming so I wrote my program on paper. Can someone find any errors in my solution? if yes , how could I correct them??

My solution:

```
.ORIG x3000
LD R0,DATA
LD R1,DATA
LOOP1 JSR INC_SUB_LEN
ADD R1,R1,#1
LD R4,LENGTH
NOT R4,R4
ADD R4,R4,#1
ADD R3,R1,R4
BRn LOOP1

INC_SUB_LEN 
LOOP ADD R2,R2,#1 
ADD R4,R0,#0
LDR R6,R0,#1
LDR R0,R0,#1
NOT R6,R6
ADD R6,R6,#1
ADD R7,R4,R6
BRnz LOOP
JSR MAX_LEN
RET

MAX_LEN 
NOT R5, R5
ADD R5, R5, #1
ADD R3,R2,R5
BRnz ELSE
ADD R5,R2,#0
NOT R5,R5
ADD R5,R5,#1
ELSE NOT R5,R5
ADD R5,R5,#1
RET


LENGTH .FILL x5000
DATA .FILL x5001
.END
```

Comment: copy/paste your code into a code-formatting block.  You wrote it on paper?  So type it in and run it in an LC3 simulator, and see if it works!  Single-step through it to make sure it works the way you expect.  (Maybe also split your big paragraph up into multiple paragraphs or bullet points.  Describing your code in English is very good, so I didn't actually downvote, but see http://idownvotedbecau.se/imagesofcode.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually had some problems with typing my code in an LC3 simulator, because I am asked to store the answers in registers and I don't exactly know how to print them. I also got many errors , of which I didn't know what was at fault. So it was easier to write it on paper like some kind of pseudocode. Thanks anyways :D

Comment: Does the increasing sequence have to start from the first element (so you just have to find the first non-increasing step), or do you have to find the longest increasing sequence out of the whole array?

Comment: Don't write code to print registers, just look at them with the debugger.  This is the point of having a debugger, instead of just a simple emulator that can only run your program.

Comment: @PeterCordes no it doesn't have to start from the first element. In the example I gave in the beginning the answer starts from the 5th element.

Comment: Ok.  I was thinking that would be a lot harder, but candidates can't overlap so there's no serious backtracking necessary.  Just compare and update the longest-seen register every time you get to the end of an increasing sequence.  (But it means you have to also check for the end of the array as an extra loop-termination condition.)

Comment: @PeterCordes if I were to write it in c++ I could actually make it work pretty fast. It is just harder to put logic into work with LC3 , thats why I am concerned I have many mistakes in the code. I know it is hard to look it on paper , but if you could give it a look , it would be awesome :D .

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to ask other people to debug your code when you haven't even tried running it yourself.  If you're having problems with syntax errors or something, google the error messages and (if you get stuck) ask a question about that, because you *will* need to figure that out at some point.  Then you can come back to this question and update it with actual valid LC3 code that you've tried.  And you'll either think it works for your test cases, or you're be stuck on some specific bug that you don't know how to solve.

Comment: This is currently kind of like a https://codereview.stackexchange.com question (which is off-topic for SO, see [ask]; this is too broad), except you haven't met their minimum standard of having a program which you've tested and think is bug-free.

Comment: And BTW, if you know how to write it in C++, you might do that and compile it (with optimization enabled) for ARM or something, on http://godbolt.org/, and look at the resulting asm to see how a compiler implements the logic.  Maybe MIPS if you use `-O3 -fno-delayed-branch`, to target a simple ISA with simple addressing modes like LC3.  Or maybe MSP430, a 16-bit ISA.  Also, the code in your question is pretty light on comments.  You normally want to at least describe what each register is being used for.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wrote the code on a simulator and tested the subroutine that finds the max . However I cannot test the rest of the code because I do not know how to insert the starting sequence of numbers. I am going to edit the post to add the code. Could you help me?

Comment: According to https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~fsieker/misc/CtoLC3.html, the LC3 pseudo-instruction for initialized data is `.fill`.  I don't know if you can write `.fill 1, 2, 3` ... or if you'd have to use a separate `.fill` for each array entry, like `.fill 1` / `.fill 2` / `.fill 3` on separate lines.  (You might want to use a label name other than `data` for the start of the array, in case that's special for LC3, like a "data section" or something.)

Comment: @PeterCordes What do I have to write before .fill though? My only knowledge is that the numbers start at x5001. When assembling , I also get the error "Unrecognized opcode or syntax error at or before "LOOP" "

Comment: On the first line, just a label like `my_array:` so you can reference that location with a symbolic name, instead of by address.  As far as I know, you can put data wherever you want, it doesn't have to start at `.org 0x5001`.  Data and code are all just bytes in memory.  So something like `my_array  .FILL #1`, then on the next line `.fill #2`.  (you may need `#` before numeric literals, which I left out. That's what the first google hit showed, anyway.  I don't know all the details of LC3 syntax; it's just one of many architectures that I'm vaguely aware of.  It's better than most toy arches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a web-based simulator: https://wchargin.github.io/lc3web/
Using this simulator, you can manually enter data into the memory map, so even if you can't fill in the memory space in the code you can do it in the GUI.

Additionally, code documentation is super critical in assembly because it does not lend itself well to self-documentation.  Make sure that labels are meaningful and you should have a block comment indicating register usage "strategy" (i.e. which ones are temporary and which are used in a longer scope and should be saved to the stack before overwriting them).  You should also have a block comment indicating the intention of every logical block, and these blocks can tend to be quite small because even simple arithmetics can be 10-20 lines.

On the second line, "LD R0, DATA" takes the actual data at the label; according to your description, you want to load the address instead of the data, for this you use "LEA" rather than "LD".  This will be required for your LDR later on to function correctly.

I'm not clear why you initialize LENGTH to be 0x5000, or why DATA is a .FILL if it's intended to be a sequence.  To block memory for a larger (more than one word) of data, you should use .BLKW and the number of bytes.  This reserves the space, and you can manually insert data into a simulator (pointy-clicky style) if you like, or use some other technique to write the data programatically.

Comment: Thank you , I will try to use the simulator :D